# How to make a JSON endpoint on Heroku or AWS?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, heroku

I am a newbie to platforms like AWS or Heroku. I have a python script that generates some JSON data. I want to run this script on AWS or Heroku and get the JSON data.
I've searched it on google a lot, but found no solution for it. Please Help!

Comment: Hi Monu. Getting severs and projects running on AWS or Heroku is no small undertaking. Might I suggest that you share what you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Actually this data is to be consumed in an android app for my personal use.

Comment: So, I need the script to update the data to an endpoint regularly.

Comment: But I have no idea where to learn about it.

Comment: @MonuKumar: sign up for one, or both, of those services and follow their tutorials and documentation. This is not the place to ask such broad questions.

Comment: done finally!!, these two links are awesome,  https://www.distelli.com/docs/tutorials/deploy-python-to-digital-ocean/ , http://pythonhow.com/deploying-your-web-application-to-the-cloud/